# Need to re-pair keyboard with Apple TV everytime

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, appletv

I have the latest Apple TV paired with Apple wireless keyboard. I can pair it in the first time, although not very smoothly. After that, I need to re-pair my keyboard with Apple TV every time. Any hints on how to keep the connection so that I don't have to re-pair?

BTW, I make the Apple TV sleep after 1 hour. I use it only occasionally, like once or twice a day.

Comment: You will have to explain the "not very smoothly"

Comment: You haven't ever paired that keyboard w anything else nearby, have you? If multiple bluetooth devices can see and pair with something, they'll fight for it; and in the end, there can be only one. If you've got other such devices, remove the keyboard from their pairing list.